# Building a native image on Mac ARM64 for linux/amd64 in sbt

Tags: docker, arm64, graalvm, sbt-native-packager

I'm using the `sbt-native-packager` plugin in sbt to generate a linux executable to be wrapped inside an alpine docker image.

Since I've switches to the new Mac arch (ARM64) this doesn't work anymore.

Using this config, the builder will default select the linux/arm64 manifest

```scala
 GraalVMNativeImage / containerBuildImage := GraalVMNativeImagePlugin
    .generateContainerBuildImage(s"ghcr.io/graalvm/graalvm-ce:ol8-java17-22")
```

The executable I create is of the type

> app: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=52b76d5e755b56293ae87fc6899655312ce4004c, with debug_info, not stripped

Trying to run this from alpine docker image will result in

> standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory

or trying to run the file via sh:

> /bin/sh: app: not found

The thing is.

I want to just build the linux/amd64 image and wrap this in a alpine image, from my macbook

Is there any way to do this?

I've tried referencing the correct digest directly

```scala
GraalVMNativeImage / containerBuildImage := GraalVMNativeImagePlugin
.generateContainerBuildImage("ghcr.io/graalvm/graalvm-ce@sha256:c2dbf1352ae7ce939dc52e0e4645d905a9366c5ea0ff5f12ef08b57d48ae847a")
```

But I think I will settle for getting the `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64,` app running in a light weight docker image for now

Comment: Ok for the arm64 issue I know to add `RUN apk add --no-cache gcompat` in the docker file

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Graal but if you use the following code in `build.sbt` you'll be able to build `amd64` images from a Mac M1 (`arm64`):

```
dockerBuildCommand := {
   if (sys.props("os.arch") != "amd64") {
     // use buildx with platform to build supported amd64 images on other CPU architectures
     // this may require that you have first run 'docker buildx create' to set docker buildx up
     dockerExecCommand.value ++ Seq("buildx", "build", "--platform=linux/amd64", "--load") ++ dockerBuildOptions.value :+ "."
   } else dockerBuildCommand.value
 }
```

Source https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/1503